# Best Collection for managing producer-consumer byte array

Tags: android, arrays, bytebuffer, consumer, producer

I'm currently using a ByteBuffer where the producer offers up an array of bytes to store.  I have a thread that constantly looks through the ByteBuffer searching for a byte sequence (a start code) to determine if I have a complete message or not.  If I find a complete message, I extract the byte array and fire an event to various listeners.  This is the way the producer sends me data, in chunks.

I have to do a lot of gyrations to make the ByteBuffer thread safe and this doesn't seem to be elegant at all.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [PriorityBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html). It is from `java.util.concurrent` package meaning, that is can be safely accessed from different threads. It is just a FIFO implementation.
Put your bytes inside this collection and wait for them in different thread.

Comment: How can I store individual bytes in a BlockingQueue?  If i store each byte array as a new Object, it will make parsing very difficult between the message fragments.